# Get each file within a directory in c on Windows

Tags: c, windows, linux, io, readdir

I am currently working on a C project where I need to scan a directory and get the file name for each file within that directory. The code needs to run on both Windows and Linux. I have the linux version using the following code.

```
DIR *dp;
int i = 0;
struct dirent *ep;
char logPath[FILE_PATH_BUF_LEN];
sprintf(logPath, "%s/logs/", logRotateConfiguration->logFileDir);
printf("Checking pre existing log count in: %s\n", logPath);
dp = opendir(logPath);

if (dp != NULL)
{
    while ((ep = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(ep->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(ep->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
else
{
    perror("Couldn't open directory");
}
logRotateConfiguration->logCount = i;
```

For this code to work I am using the `#include <dirent.h>` but have found this to not be compatible for Windows. Therefore in my header file I have used an ifdef to include dirent.h if on Linux but not sure what I can use for it being on Windows.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list files on Windows you can use [`FindFirstFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`FindNextFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For an example see [Listing the Files in a Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I think OP wanted something generic to run on both: `The code needs to run on both Windows and Linux`

Comment: @mike, I don't think so, given the title of the question and nothing in the question suggests conditional preprocessor code inclusion is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

[There is a free windows implementation of dirent.h (clicky)](http://www.softagalleria.net/dirent.php)

Answer (score 0):

MinGW ([link](http://mingw.org)) has `dirent.h`. I have found no documentation about its specific implementation of dirent on the net, but i assume it is similar enough to unix-derivatives version. You can look at the header-file and then decide whether to use it.

Notes about the other answers: I dont know about the version from softagalleria.net, so i cannot talk about it, but about the `FindFirstFile/FindNextFile`-API: If you decide to use it make sure to use the "Unicode"-Versions (actually UCS-2) because the Ascii-Versions only allow very limited path-lengths. To use the Unicode-Version define the macro and make sure you prepend all paths with `\\?\`.